# Invoking tag in grails gsp does not work

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I am using the spring core security plugin and try to invoke the `<sec:ifAnyGranted />` tag directly from EL like so:

```
sec.ifAnyGranted(roles: 'ROLE1, ROLE2, ...')
```

This however does not work as nothing is returned from the method. However if i try to use the tag in the following way it does work:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE1, ROLE2, ...">
```

The reason i can't use the second is because i need to combine two criteria in order to restrict access to a particular element in a page, one of which being the user's participation in a particular list of roles. In order to achieve this i am using the `<sec:access />` tag in the following way:

```
<sec:access expression="${sec.ifAnyGranted(roles:'ROLE1,ROLE2,...') || (expression 2)">
   ...
</sec:access>
```

Sadly, this does not work for me. Could anyone help out?

Comment: The expression take text 'and','or' instead of &&, ||. (Yes I know this is an ancient question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted(roles) directly from your view.

Alternatively, you may pass body to sec.ifAnyGranted(roles:'comma separated string','string for body')

**EXAMPLE**

```
<g:if test="${sec.ifAnyGranted(roles: 'ROLE_USER_BUSINESS', 'null')}">
    BUSINESS
</g:if>
<g:else>
    SOMETHING TLESE
</g:else>
```

Comment: I did solve it like you propose, but thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your tag usage without any body (calling sec.ifAnyGranted directly is equivalent to using the tag without any body) doesn't produce the result expected by you is that the ifAnyGranted tag is implemented in the following way:

```
    if(springSecurityService.ifAnyGranted(comma separated roles here)){
      out << body()
    }
```

You can modify the tag implementation to cater to your requirements. Try something like this:

```
   if(springSecurityService.ifAnyGranted(comma separated roles here)){
     if(!body()){
       return true 
     }else{
     out << body();     
     }
   }
```

You will have to add the following statement to the spring security taglib.

```
    static returnObjectForTags = ['ifAnyGranted']
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the spring security taglib directly, you can create a new taglib and a corresponding tag to implement **your version** of the "ifAnyGranted".
I would recommend the latter. One of the reasons for this is that if you choose the former approach, you will have to modify the spring security tag lib every time you decide to upgrade the plugin.

Comment: Don't edit plugin code - it makes it harder to use the plugin since you need to check it into source control or use your own custom build. Just create your own tag in your application.